# PAM: Confirm old password before changing to new password in SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, pam, passwd, pam-unix

OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10

```
Login as root
server:~ # cat /etc/pam.d/common-password | grep -i ^PASS
password  required       pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=9 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 difok=4
password  required       pam_pwcheck.so  nullok use_authtok remember=5
password  required       pam_unix2.so    nullok use_authtok


Login as user
user@server:~> passwd user
Changing password for user.
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
Old Password:
Password changed.
```

I want it to ask for Old password first before changing new password

Comment: I got it fixed by putting "password  required       pam_pwcheck.so" above pam_cracklib